# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str Python3.6.8

Tags: python, string, byte, python-3.6

My script I got from the web

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print ("\n*********************************************************************")
print ("Cisco IOU License Generator - Kal 2011, python port of 2006 C version")
import os
import socket
import hashlib
import struct
# get the host id and host name to calculate the hostkey
hostid=os.popen("hostid").read().strip()
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ioukey=int(hostid,16)
for x in hostname:
 ioukey = ioukey + ord(x)
print ("hostid=" + hostid +", hostname="+ hostname + ", ioukey=" + hex(ioukey)[2:])
# create the license using md5sum
iouPad1='\x4B\x58\x21\x81\x56\x7B\x0D\xF3\x21\x43\x9B\x7E\xAC\x1D\xE6\x8A'
iouPad2='\x80' + 39*'\0'
md5input=iouPad1 + iouPad2 + struct.pack('!L', ioukey) + iouPad1
iouLicense=hashlib.md5(md5input).hexdigest()[:16]
# add license info to $HOME/.iourc
print ("\n*********************************************************************")
print ("Create the license file $HOME/.iourc with this command:")
print (" echo -e '[license]\\n" + hostname + " = " + iouLicense + ";'" + " | tee $HOME/.iourc ")
print ("\nThe command adds the following text to $HOME/.iourc:")
print ("[license]\n" + hostname + " = " + iouLicense + ";")
# disable phone home feature
print ("\n*********************************************************************")
print ("Disable the phone home feature with this command:")
print (" grep -q -F '127.0.0.1 xml.cisco.com' /etc/hosts || echo '127.0.0.1 xml.cisco.com' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts")
print ("\nThe command adds the following text to /etc/hosts:")
print ("127.0.0.1 xml.cisco.com")
print ("\n*********************************************************************")
```

For some reason im gettin this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    md5input=iouPad1 + iouPad2 + struct.pack('!L', ioukey) + iouPad1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

I am trying to use this script in a linux distribution for my GNS3, but I am not able to run this script in Python v3.6.8. Any solutions to this problem? could someone send me the correct script?

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing
`md5input=iouPad1 + iouPad2 + struct.pack('!L', ioukey) + iouPad1`
with
`md5input=iouPad1 + iouPad2 + struct.pack('!L', ioukey).decode() + iouPad1`.